# Tkinter increase resolution to save to PDF

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am into a bill design step using tkinter.

I created a Tk() 500x705 (A4 proportions) but I got resolution problems when saving as PDF with Imagegrab (low pixels to print) .

To solve this I follow the idea to increase window and widgets to increase the font sizes also, and stay with the same design. But now the tk() window is oversized and doesnt fit in the screen, so I am having problems to capture the image to save.

Does anyone know to solve this problem? the original is 500x705 and using fonts size 4-6, so in A4 they have low pixels and are blured.

I am trying this because there are a bunch of frames and labels to go 1 by1 redesigning widths and sizes.

Maybe I can use other approach?

```
def change_font(frames, factor):
for frame in frames:
    for child in frame.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, tkinter.Label):
            
            current_font = child.cget("font")
            font_info = current_font.split()
            
            
            if 'bold' in current_font:
                
                if len(font_info) > 1 and font_info[1].isdigit():
                    current_font_size = int(font_info[1])
                    
                    
                    new_sizefont = current_font_size * factor
                    
                    
                    new_font = (font_info[0], new_sizefont, 'bold')
                    child.config(font=new_font)
            else:
                
                if len(font_info) > 1 and font_info[1].isdigit():
                    current_font_size = int(font_info[1])
                    
                    
                    new_sizefont = current_font_size * factor
                    
                    
                    new_font = (font_info[0], new_sizefont)
                    child.config(font=new_font)

def change_window_size(proforma, factor):

      original_width = proforma.winfo_width()
      original_height = proforma.winfo_height()


      new_width = int(original_width * factor)
      new_height = int(original_height * factor)


      proforma.geometry(f"{new_width}x{new_height}")

def get_screen():


      change_window_size(proforma, 1.9)
      change_font(frames, 2)


      proforma.after(2000, capturar_y_guardar)


     #####code to capture window
```

[image: Bill design (sources 2 .csv)]

Comment: just rasterize your "bill" using matplotlib in-memory, you don't need to use tkinter or ImageGrab, you can show it after it is saved to disk through your GUI as an image, which could be zoomable (using a matplotlib canvas).

Comment: that produces the same problem: if not resized the data is blur (i need more pixels in fonts to print in A4) and if I resize the window, it dont capture the non-visible window

Comment: You don't print things to screen, you do the whole thing in memory using matplotlib, there is no resizing involved, you can have a zoom functionality if you want to preview the image after it is converted to pdf, not before.

Comment: I post you the bill design to you can explain if it is possible.
It is done in tkinter reading csv files and doing some calculations also

Comment: it is not a simple dataframe or plot, is a bill full design about labels and frames so matplot is not a solution I guess